# Does every matrix have a eigenvalue that sends the matrix to the zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to write a program to find the kernel of a given matrix. I haven't been satisfied with any gaussian elimination programs that I've found - which of course could be used to identify the kernel.

I do know that [eigen lib has a function to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1EigenSolver.html). I was wondering if it would be possible for me to use it for finding the kernel.

However, this would depend on every matrix having a non-zero eigenvector `x` such that 
`Ax = 0`. Is this possible? Or am I inferring an erroneous relationship between eigenvectors and kernels?

Comment: Indeed, a matrix has nontrivial nullspace $\iff$ an eigenvalue of zero exists.  Any basis for the eigenspace with a zero eigenvalue is exactly a basis for the matrix's nullspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a non-zero eigenvector $x$ such that $Ax=0$, then $x$ belong to the kernel.

Otherwise, kernel of the matrix just consist of the zero vector. Every non-singular matrix falls into this category.

From the eigen lib, you just have to extract columns of $V$ that corresponds to zero eigenvalues if any to find a basis for the kernel. I am assuming that you are focusing on square matrices.